# Spring MVC OptionalValidatorFactoryBean not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have set up a Spring MVC (4)+Postgresql+JPA app and I encountered the following situation:
I want to set up custom queries for my "User" repository so added these lines to the existing (empty) UserRepository:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    @Query("select u from User u where u.Email = ?1")
    User findByEmail(String emailAddress);

}
```

With the empty Repository, everything is OK with the server, with the verison above I got the following exception on startup:

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;**

nested exception is

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.springapp.mvc.Repositories.AccountRepository** com.springapp.mvc.AccountController.accountRepository;

nested exception is

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean] for bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0' defined in null;

nested exception is

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean**

Even tough I have OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java in the jar (extracted it) provided with maven. I'm really confused.

Comment: Is the library added to the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today i come across the same problem , It caused by jar confliction . spring-context3.1-RELEASE.jar and spring-context4.1-RELEASE.jar , my project using spring4.1 , but spring3.1-context is also downloaded because of maven dependencies,then I remvoed spring3.1.jar ,all goes well

Comment: Thank you, I've already abandoned my project because of this error but I'm happy that it has a theoretical solution now

Comment: where can I remove spring3.1.jar ?
I also occur this error and I cannot fix it.

Comment: where can I remove spring3.1.jar ?
I also occur this error and I cannot fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Spring Context in your maven dependencies, like;

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```