# Spring - MVC Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I suspect the problem lies in the pom.xml where there are some other dependency that I have to add or changing up some information in my dispatcher servlet. I got this error after trying to implement the JSR 303 and JSR 349. Any help is appreciated.

I'm getting the following root errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
```

Dispatcher servlet class

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<!-- Used to search beans Include search for controllers, services, componenets -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.Alex" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- View resolver to lead user to .jsp file -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
```

My Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.Alex</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

EDIT: Error trying to do a maven clean

```html
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project Spring: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\Java Workspace\SpringMVC\target\tomcat\logs\access_log.2020-06-28 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate Validator java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163434/hibernate-validator-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o)

Answer (score 0):

Surely its a version mismatch between spring-mvc and hibernate validator. Manually browse through hibernate-validator jar to check for the presence of this class
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl

Comment: I don't see it

https://gyazo.com/36b5651d0a9ad8bb278f2a6e91ca4549

Comment: Are these helpful?

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255432/spring-mvc-optionalvalidatorfactorybean-not-found

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986200/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-validation-beanvalidation-opt

Comment: Tried those, no luck

Comment: is your project available at github ? i can give it a try.

Comment: I uploaded here https://tmpfiles.org/download/57556/SpringMVC.rar

Comment: https://tmpfiles.org/download/57572/TomcatLOgs.txt
https://tmpfiles.org/download/57573/Capture.PNG

I am able to hit test and login page with success.
I think u r trying something wrong to start the application.

Comment: I start with maven build

Comment: 1) mvn clean install . This will produce .war file in target directory. 2) copy this .war file inside tomcat's war folder. 3) start tomcat using start.sh